# how find out the process description from process Id on redshift?

Tags: deadlock, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to debug a deadlock on Redshift:

```
SQL Execution failed ...  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 7679 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 307602 of database 108260; blocked by process 7706.
Process 7706 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 307569 of database 108260; blocked by process 7679.
```

Is there a sql query to get a description for process ids 7679 and 7706?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from stl_query where pid=XXX
```

This will give you the query txt which will help you identify your query.
You can also query **stv_locks** to check is there are any current updates in the database, and **str_tr_conflict** will display all the lock conflict on the table.

Comment: Process Ids in the error message are 4 digits ... that doesn't match anything in the system tables pid columns which are more like 10 digits